# Sharepoint with silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint. I wrote a simple RIA MCF silverlight app which runs all the queries right on my server. Now I tried make it available on a Sharepoint testing site. I loaded the xap file but Sharepoint throws me tons of load operation exceptions when it tries to load the app, apparently having problems with the EDM in the app. What do I need to do here? Is the xap the only thing I need to load on the shared documents folder? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Justin,

There are few steps you need to follow to load the Silverlight XAP in sharepoint.

1. You need to create RIA service as an independently hostable web application (.svc)
   Follow the guidelines available [here](http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/post/Things-you-can-do-with-WCF-RIA-Services-and-a-regular-svc-file.aspx)
2. Once you have the solution ready. Host service on IIS and make sure that it is functioning correctly.
3. Configure the .svc in the web.config of the hosting web application and access the same in your silverlight application as below

   new LoggingContext(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingServiceUrl"]);
4. Load the xap on sharepoint site and in the configuration section provide links to .svc services.
   [image: Configure Other settings of the silverlight web part to point to the service (.svc) link]

Comment: Thanks, Sandeep, does it mean I have to have the sharepoint, silverlight, and Entity Datamodel on the same server? In my case, they are not running on the same machine right now. My silverlight RIA MCS is on one machine and I am trying to get my app to the department sharepoint server.

Comment: No, it is not required to have sharepoint and ria service on the save server. Of course, when you upload your silverlight module on sharepoint, it will be part of it. Having RIA and Sharepoint on different physical machines is a valid scenario. Application should function without any issues. I have hosted my application in this manner.